# Changing redirect login path for guests?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

Suppose a menu's (or article's) access is set to **registered users** only.

Path to the page : `http://localhost/menu`

when this **URL** is directly access by any **GUEST USER**, he's redirected to :

`http://localhost/...?view=login` which asks him to login first.

How to change the path to redirect page..i have made a custom login page, i want it to be redirected to my custom made login page and not to `http://localhost/...?view=login`. Which file needs to be edited to acheive that?

Comment: This should do the job http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/12395 I have used it and works

Comment: Nope, it didn't work!

Comment: I looked everywhere for a solution to this issue. I have a custom login menu/page and wanted anyone (guest, etc) directed there. This variable *view=login* was redirecting users to some template and I tried everything, even hacking it together. This solution above by @Saibbyweb is so simple and does the trick. (If necessary, simply copy the PHP files to the folder YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login) then modify as stated above....it worked like a charm!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself! :)

You need to edit this file : `/templates/your_template/html/com_users/login/default.php`
or if your template folder doesn't consist of html folder, edit this one:
`/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default.php`

and change

```
if ($this->user->get('guest')):
echo $this->loadTemplate('login');
```

to

```
if ($this->user->get('guest')):
header("Location: URL_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to make your login page look different, you can do a template override and no need to redirect to a different page.
Find your templates folder and select the template you are using. 
Create an html folder if you do not have one.
The component you wanna override is *com_users*.

If you have a look at `/components/com_users/views` folder, you can see all the views that can be overriden in the template folder. The one we need now is in the login folder. 
`/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl` - there are *default.php* *default_login.php* and *default_logout.php*.

You have already created an html folder in your template, now you need to copy these files in the following location:

```
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login
```

That will result in having 3 files:

```
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login/default.php
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login/default_login.php
/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/login/default_logout.php
```

You do not need the *tmpl* folder.

You can edit the *default_login.php* to do the override.

Comment: i have already customized my site alot! i just need to change the redirect path..otherwise i need to make changes in around 50-60 pages :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a plugin, which will check the url and Usergroup. If you user is guest then you can redirect user to desired url.

Below link may help you.

- [Creating Joomla Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)
- [onAfterRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterRoute)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @saibbyweb resulted in an infinite redirect loop in Joomla 3.9.

I then figured out that my problem was with the component I was trying to access, `com_akeebasubs`, which used:

`$this->container->platform->redirect(\JUri::base() .'index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=' . $myURI);`

The redirect worked properly after I changed this line to:

`$this->container->platform->redirect(\JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=' . $myURI));`

You do need to have a `User > Login Form` menu item.

Comment: Thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour] and perhaps tell us about yourself by editing your profile.  I look foward to seeing more of your insights shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change where the user is going to be redirected after login and logout, you van do this in the login module of joomla. There are 2 fileds for this.

Comment: when the user is detected as guest, he's directed to the login page `http://localhost/...?view=login` (which say please login first) , i want to change that **URL**